# egrep regex match line break

Tags: command-line, grep

I need to match string `update sims` in `.sql` files to prevent any update to table `sims`. I have `cat test.sql | grep -iE '^\s*UPDATE\s+sims,*\s+'`, which will not wrongly match, say `update simsfdafsa`. It will match `update sims set` and `update  sims, table1, table2...`.

But I cannot match any line break char. If someone wrote:

```
update sims
set dfa=fdag
```

The grep fails. There's a line break after the `sims` above. I tried `\n` and `\s`, but neither worked. I wonder how to match line break in egrep?

Comment: With GNU grep: `grep -Poz 'update[ \n]sims[ \n]set[ \n]dfa=fdag' file`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using this as a test file:

```
cat ~/tmp/test
update sims
set dfa=fdag
update simsafing
update sims, test1
update simss
```

this regex parses it as you require:

```
egrep 'update sims$|sims[, ]' ~/tmp/test

update sims
update sims, test1
```

### edit

this page https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html explains all the regex patterns that sed knows about (it is basic regex). Because sed is 'greedy' (once you've read that page you'll know what that means) it attempts to match as much of the pattern as possible, so [, ] will match as many spaces or commas in a run as possible.

Comment: That is so cool, can you briefly explain what | and [, ] means? Thanks.

Comment: I mean why [, ] can match more than one white spaces?